# Mediawiki templates: How to get a list of parameter names?

Tags: parameter-passing, mediawiki

I'm working on a set of complex Mediawiki templates.  It's intended that there be an "outer layer" page for basic editors to work on, where they can just fill in parameter values and supplementary text.  This is passed on to an interim template, which breaks out all of the parameters to the various different 2nd-level templates which actually handle all the data organization and page display.  There are something like 250 parameters which could potentially be passed, though likely only 20 to 25 from any one main page.

Is there a way to get a list of what named parameters are passed to a template?  Rather than a giant list of {{#if {{{arg}} | arg = {{{arg}}} }}s, it'd be much cleaner to only handle those arguments which already are known to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the extension Semantic MediaWiki, you will have lots of options on handling parameters (as semantic properties). The extension Semantic Result Formats gives you even more options on how to display results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. Remember, that the template engine of MediaWiki IS NOT a programming language :)

However, without knowing the exact use case, you probably can solve your problem by defining default values. Instead of:

```
{{#if {{{arg}}} | {{{arg}}} | default }}
```

you can do something like this:

```
{{{arg|default}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) extension and turn your templates into simple wrappers that invoke a Scribunto module. Scribunto modules are Lua scripts and have access to all parameters, whether they have been declared in the wikitext of the wrapper template or not.